# Springboot @DataJpaTest mode=oracle

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, database-migration

I tried and searched but can't figure it out: how to set `MODE=Oracle` for @DataJpaTest test?

*Backstory:* I have lots of liquibase migration scripts, unless I set `MODE=Oracle`, lots of scripts fail to run due to issues with data. For example: if `timestamp` is `null` (which is valid), in Oracle mode the data loads and tests passes, if I take `MODE=oracle` out then liquibase migration fails.

*The problem:* `@DataJpaTest` creates random database in memory - which is cool, but mode is NOT set and data fails to migrate. For Application level test following configuration works good:

```
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    changeLog: "classpath:migrations.xml"
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHEMA;SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH=PUBLIC,MYSCHEMA
    user: sa
    password: sa
```

I know I can do following (and it works):

```
spring:
  test:
    database:
      replace: NONE
```

Is there a way to set `MODE=Oracle` (by default or otherwise) for @DataJpaTest tests?

Comment: If you use Oracle in production you should use Oracle for tests. Check out Testcontainers.